# How to satisfy PCL cmake warnings

Tags: cmake, point-cloud-library

I would like to know if there is a way to make these cmake build warnings go away without installing extra libraries:

```
** WARNING ** io features related to ensenso will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to davidSDK will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to dssdk will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to pcap will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to png will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to libusb-1.0 will be disabled
```

Comment: Can you provide us more detail on what you are doing? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There is a related post [here](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/2651#issuecomment-450544976) with some solutions for getting rid of some of these...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building the library from source, just comment out this [line](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/5e0cb7d3a1634ff33232b48ced9c91b37bc9b837/PCLConfig.cmake.in#L340) in `PCLConfig.cmake.in`

Comment: In that case comment out the above [line](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/5e0cb7d3a1634ff33232b48ced9c91b37bc9b837/PCLConfig.cmake.in#L340) from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl/PCLConfig.cmake`

Comment: Thanks shrijit!

After diving into the cmake source files, there's no apparent way to mute just the libraries that I am not using. There is only the method mentioned above that disables all of the warnings about unavailable libraries. Not ideal, but does what I need. :)